# How to fix ReactRouter error "Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid"?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, single-page-application

I have tried this tutorial on ReactRouter: https://www.kirupa.com/react/creating_single_page_app_react_using_react_router.htm

The demo page and complete source code is here (JS is in the HTML file): https://www.kirupa.com/react/examples/react_router_final.htm

When I try to implement something similar I get error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `ComponentRoot`.
```

I noticed, that when I changed the React and Babel version in the Kirupa's demo app (complete source code in the link above), to:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/4.0.0-0/react-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.19.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

I get the same error in this demo app. So the React or Babel version change is causing this problem.

How can I fix this demo app to work with the newset version of React and Babel?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial seems to cover `react-router@2.x.x` and you used `react-router@4.x.x` which is complete rewrite with different approach and API.

Use the v2 to match with API described in tutorial or use docs for v4 (https://react-router.now.sh/).
Notice that v4 is still in alpha.